# Better way to import Vite plugin

Tags: javascript, import

I get an error when following the usage for [vite-plugin-plain-text](https://github.com/zheeeng/vite-plugin-plain-text#readme):

```
import plainText from 'vite-plugin-plain-text';

console.log(plainText);  // Check what we imported.
let config = plainText(/LICENSE$/);
```

The output is:

```
{ default: [Function: plainText] }
> plainTextPlugin is not a function
```

Instead of importing a function, the import statement imported an object with a function named `default`. In the module JS file, `plainText` was exported like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
...
exports.default = plainText;
```

I was able to successfully import like this:

```
import plainTextPlugin from 'vite-plugin-plain-text';
let plainText = plainTextPlugin.default;
let config = plainText(/LICENSE$/);
```

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this import? [JavaScript ‪Module Cheatsheet](https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-module-cheatsheet-7bd474f1d829) doesn't have any pattern for importing a library that was exported like this library. Interestingly, the TS source code exports the module like this:

```
export default function plainText (...)
```

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, your initial `import` is correct for the `export` shown at the end. Something somewhere (a bundler, etc.) is adding an erroneous extra layer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm actually using SvelteKit, which uses Vite for building. Could that make any difference? Or are you talking about whatever built the plugin distribution files? (index.ts -> index.js)

Comment: I *suspect* the latter, but I'm afraid I don't really know which end the problem is at, if not both. :-D

Comment: I wouldn't call it *better*, but you might be able to do `const plainText = await import("vite-plugin-plain-text").then(({ default: { default: { plainText }}}) => playText); let config = plainText(/LICENSE$/);` (or it may need just one level of `default`) ;-D